# Novo acordo ortográfico obrigatório em 2016 no Brasil

Tags: discussion

As regras do Acordo Ortográfico da Língua Portuguesa são obrigatórias no Brasil a partir de 01 Janeiro de 2016.

Em uso desde 2009, mudanças como o fim do trema e novas regras para o uso do hífen e de acentos diferenciais agora são oficiais com a entrada em vigor do acordo, adiada por três anos pelo governo brasileiro.

Assinado em 1990 com outros Estados-Membros da Comunidade de Países de Língua Portuguesa (CPLP) para padronizar as regras ortográficas, o acordo foi ratificado pelo Brasil em 2008 e implementado sem obrigatoriedade em 2009. A previsão inicial era que as regras fossem cobradas oficialmente a partir de 1° de janeiro de 2013, mas, após polêmicas e críticas da sociedade, o governo adiou a entrada em vigor para 1° de janeiro de 2016.

O Brasil é o terceiro dos oito países que assinaram o tratado a tornar obrigatórias as mudanças, que já estão em vigor em Portugal e Cabo Verde. Angola, Moçambique, Guiné-Bissau, São Tomé e Príncipe e Timor-Leste ainda não aplicam oficialmente as novas regras ortográficas.

Com a padronização da língua, a CPLP pretende facilitar o intercâmbio cultural e científico entre os países e ampliar a divulgação do idioma e da literatura em língua portuguesa, já que os livros passam a ser publicados sob as novas regras, sem diferenças de vocabulários entre os países. De acordo com o Ministério da Educação, o acordo alterou 0,8% dos vocábulos da língua portuguesa no Brasil e 1,3% em Portugal.

### Alfabeto, trema e acentos

Entre as principais mudanças, está a ampliação do alfabeto oficial para 26 letras, com o acréscimo do k, w e y. As letras já são usadas em várias palavras do idioma, como nomes indígenas e abreviações de medidas, mas estavam fora do vocábulo oficial.

O trema – dois pontos sobre a vogal u – foi eliminado, e pode ser usado apenas em nomes próprios. No entanto, a mudança vale apenas para a escrita, e palavras como linguiça, cinquenta e tranquilo continuam com a mesma pronúncia.

Os acentos diferenciais também deixaram de existir, de acordo com as novas regras, eliminando a diferença gráfica entre pára (do verbo parar) e para (preposição), por exemplo. Há exceções como as palavras pôr (verbo) e por (preposição) e pode (presente do indicativo do verbo poder) e pôde (pretérito do indicativo do verbo poder), que tiveram os acentos diferenciais mantidos.

O acento circunflexo foi retirado de palavras terminadas em “êem”, como nas formas verbais leem, creem, veem e em substantivos como enjoo e voo.

Já o acento agudo foi eliminado nos ditongos abertos “ei” e “oi” (antes "éi" e "ói”), dando nova grafia a palavras como colmeia e  jiboia.

O hífen deixou de ser usado em dois casos: quando a segunda parte da palavra começar com s ou r (contra-regra passou a ser contrarregra), com exceção de quando o prefixo terminar em r (super-resistente), e quando a primeira parte da palavra termina com vogal e a segunda parte começa com vogal (auto-estrada passou a ser autoestrada).

A grafia correta das palavras conforme as regras do acordo podem ser consultadas no Vocabulário Ortográfico da Língua Portuguesa (Volp), disponível no site da [Academia Brasileira de Letras (ABL)](http://www.academia.org.br) e por meio de aplicativo para smartphones e tablets, que pode ser baixado em dispositivos Android, pelo Google Play, e em dispositivos da Apple, pela App Store.

<sub>Fonte: http://agenciabrasil.ebc.com.br/geral/noticia/2016-01/novo-acordo-ortografico-e-obrigatorio-partir-de-hoje</sub>

Comment: http://www.priberam.pt/docs/AcOrtog90.pdf

Comment: Eu ia justamente postar uma pergunta relativa à entrada em vigor do novo acordo. Ele só está valendo no Brasil, Portugal e Cabo Verde, certo? E os outros 5 signatários que ainda não aderiram, quando adotarão oficialmente o tratado, finalmente "unificando" o português?

Comment: @gmauch então eu não tenho certeza, mais tarde vou tentar editar, mas acredito que a data seja para o Brasil. Acredito que demais países podem ter suas próprias datas.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Bom, vou criar a pergunta então, talvez alguém da comunidade saiba (ou pesquise) e possa responder!

Comment: Ao perguntar ou responder, ou ainda ao editar perguntas e respostas, assume-se então como correto o que estiver de acordo com a nova reforma? Pergunto isso porque nunca abandonei o costume de tremar as palavras, e acredito que remover as tremas piora a língua e dificulta seu aprendizado, especialmente para estrangeiros.