# A palavra Acreano

Tags: discussion

Isto não é uma duvida é um debate, sobre o acordo ortográfico, acho interessante discutir isto pois é uma polémica no estado do Acre (Brasil).

### O caso:

Desde a época que o Acre deixou de ser parte da Bolívia (acredito 1903) e passou a ser território brasileiro o termo usado para se definir aos cidadãos deste estado é *acreano*, muitos prédios e locais públicos carregam o nome `acreano` em suas fachadas e talvez documentos de cartório ou algo assim.

Os habitantes naturais do Acre são agora denominados acrianos [[1](http://educacao.uol.com.br/disciplinas/portugues/adjetivos-patrios-veja-gentilicos-dos-estados-do-brasil.htm)]. No singular o gentílico é acriano. Até a entrada em vigor do Acordo Ortográfico de 1990, a grafia correta era acreano no singular e no plural acreanos.

Em 2009, com o novo acordo ortográfico, a mudança do gentílico gerou polêmica entre a Academia Acriana de Letras e a Academia Brasileira de Letras, alegando que a mudança significaria a negação das raízes históricas e culturais do estado, mudando a última letra do topônimo de `E` para `I`. Embora ainda gere discussões sobre o assunto, é notório que a imensa maioria da população do estado não gostou e não adotou o "novo" gentílico, continuando a se autodenominarem acreanos [[2](http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/educacao/2009/03/540006-novo-acordo-ortografico-gera-polemica-no-acre.shtml)].

> **Relacionado:** [Novo acordo ortográfico obrigatório em 2016 no Brasil](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/215/8)
>
> Nota: Convém saber que a terminação `-eano` só aparece em derivados de nomes próprios terminados em `-é` por exemplo:
>
> - Taubaté = taubateano
>
> Ou terminados em ditongo, por exemplo:
>
> - Coreia = coreano; Galileu = galileano; Montevidéu = montevideano
>
> <sub>http://www.portuguesnarede.com/2011/11/acreano-ou-acriano.html</sub>

O problema e argumento do povo deste estado (Acre) é que eles são *acr**e**anos* há mais de 100 anos e como disse no começo várias "coisas importantes" para eles usam o termo *acr**e**ano*.

Somos uma comunidade de português, acho que poderíamos expressar nossas opiniões.

E você o que acha?

Comment: Eu sou um bocado conservador no que toca à Língua portuguesa, e por isso acho que esse termo deve ser mantido. Não me incomoda tirarem consoantes mudas de palavras, mas incomoda-me um bocado alterar palavras assim, ainda para mais quando é um nome de uma região ou de um povo.

Comment: @ANeves quanto erro de ortografia eu tenho hehehe, obrigado pela edição.

Comment: És uma vítima da homofonia, Guilherme... na maior parte destes casos as palavras soam iguais antes e depois da correção, em pt-BR, mas diferentes em pt-PT. :)

Comment: @ANeves sim é verdade, fico mais interessado em voltar a participar do site com tantos usuários que você com bastante conhecimento. Só edita o comentário, Guilerme (falta o H).

Comment: (Ups! Obrigado, corrigi.)

Answer (score 2):

Percebo o argumento, mas não vejo grande problema com a mudança.

- Ia-se à «pharmácia», agora à farmácia.
- Conhecia-se um «Luiz», agora um Luís.
- Era-se «actor», agora ator.
- Era-se «acreano», agora acriano.

Percebo a resistência dos acreanos a essa mudança, mas não é por isso que eles vão perder identidade cultural.
Poder-se-ia pôr isto nestes termos: «pode-se tirar um acreano do Acre, mas não se pode tirar o Acre de um acreano».

Neste caso em concreto, *eu* acho mais útil a simplificação gramatical do que a tradição histórica. Mas também acho perfeitamente válida a opinião oposta.